# Can't pass a reference to a protocol where self is specified

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project using the [NVActivityIndicatorView](https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView) library and I am trying to extract some logic from two view controllers. Both view controllers conform to `NVActivityIndicatorViewable` whose definition is:

```swift
// From the libaray. I don't want to modify this.
public protocol NVActivityIndicatorViewable {}

public extension NVActivityIndicatorViewable where Self: UIViewController
{
    func startAnimating( ... ) { ... }
    func stopAnimating() { ... }
}
```

And as a result, I expected to be able to pass one of these view controllers in and use the `startAnimation` and `stopAnimation` methods on it.

```swift
func sharedLogic(sender: NVActivityIndicatorViewable)
{
    sender.startAnimating( ... )
    sender.stopAnimating()
}
```

However, this fails with the compiler error `'NVActivityIndicatorViewable' requires that 'NVActivityIndicatorViewable' inherit from 'UIViewController'`

Trying this with `sender: UIViewController`, this fails with the compile time error `Value of 'UIViewController' has no member 'startAnimating'` as I expected.

```swift
func sharedLogic(sender: UIViewController) 
{
    sender.startAnimating( ... )
    sender.stopAnimating()
}
```

**I have found two potential solutions:**

1. Create an empty subclass that specifies both these types: (This new type doesn't contain any logic)

```swift
class ActivityIndicatorViewController: UIViewController, NVActivityIndicatorViewable { }
```

2. Use an extension to specify all view controllers can be activity indicators: (This causes `redundant conformance` errors on many classes)

```swift
extension UIViewController: NVActivityIndicatorViewable { }
```

Can I accomplish this without creating a new type?

Environment settings:

- Xcode version: 10.1
- iOS Deployment Target: 9.0
- Swift version: 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is a [composition type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID454) - a type that both inherits from `UIViewController` and conforms to `NVActivityIndicatorViewable`:

```
UIViewController & NVActivityIndicatorViewable
```

You can use this directly as the parameter type for your method:

```
func sharedLogic(sender: UIViewController & NVActivityIndicatorViewable)
```

Or you can create a `typealias` for it (though I can't think of a shorter name):

```
typealias SomeShorterName = UIViewController & NVActivityIndicatorViewable
```

And then you can use `SomeShorterName` as the parameter type.

Answer (score 2):

You set constraint on the protocol and extended the constrained one. So if you want those two functions, you need a `UIViewContoller` conformed to your protocol.

Move functions to the original protocol to get what you need.

```
public protocol NVActivityIndicatorViewable {
    func startAnimating( ... )
    func stopAnimating()
}
```

**Update due to comment:**

If you want to leave the original Protocol untouched, use composition type for the function:

```
func sharedLogic(sender: UIViewController & NVActivityIndicatorViewable) {
    sender.startAnimating()
    sender.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: That would be the best case, however, that protocol exists in a the library and outside the scope of what I want to modify for this issue. Thanks though!

Comment: You should mention your limitations in the question. Check the update.